# Using Zip2Secure in a windows bat file, with users specifying the password

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Good afternoon,

I've developed a BAT file to burn encrypted data to a CD, using the command line interface within the system.

this works really well, however the password is only alterable from within the BAT file

```
ChilkatZipSE.exe -encrypt 128 -password <Password> -autotemp -run run.bat "D:\CD Burner\pre burn\disc.zip"
```

I need a way for users to change that themselves, without having to go into the BAT file.

I would ideally like a second bat file that can navigate to the location of the  (which is fixed and known) and change it when required. the password length is always the same.

Is this possible? - I won't be able to install any other files / programmes on the computer in question to do this.

if not, do we have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into using set /p to get input from the using and using that as the password?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the password into a separate batch file, which just saves the password into an environment variable. You can call that separate batch file from your main batch file. And because that separate file is very simple, it would be easy to regenerate.

password.bat:

```
SET ENCRYPTED_ZIP_PASSWORD=12345
```

burn-cd.bat:

```
CALL password.bat
ChilkatZipSE.exe -encrypt 128 -password %ENCRYPTED_ZIP_PASSWORD% -autotemp -run run.bat "D:\CD Burner\pre burn\disc.zip"

REM It might be a good idea to clear the environment variable when we're done
SET ENCRYPTED_ZIP_PASSWORD=
```

change-password.bat: (Usage: `change-password <new-password>`)

```
ECHO SET ENCRYPTED_ZIP_PASSWORD=%1 >password.bat
```